# How to display High Dynamic Range(HDR) image format in overleaf/latex

Tags: graphics, overleaf

I use HDR image format (.hdr) frequently for my reports, but I don't know any package that helps with displaying such files without compressing to JPGs,
Is it possible to import HDR directly in latex?

Comment: No, I'm afraid this isn't possible. If you have a conversion program that can embed them into PDF without (too much) compression you can use those PDFs instead of JPGs. Or you use PNGs (but I'd pre-convert those to PDF as well, as PNG takes pretty long to be input by LaTeX).

Comment: If you are generating pdf you are limited to what pdf supports

Comment: @Skillmon - since pre-conversion of png to pdf  is mentioned here - what is the best LaTex friendly way to do this - via standalone class?

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn with whichever tool you can get good optimized PDFs that look like you want :) You could do this with `standalone`, yes. But scripting this with ImageMagick or similar tools would certainly be easier.